# How to configure IIS 7 to use a subdirectory as the default document?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, iis-6, iis-express

The default document is available in the subdirectroy in my website(Account/login.aspx) i want to set this page as default document in IIS manager how can able to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing may be to keep your default document in the root with code like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" %>
<% Response.Redirect("~/account/login.aspx") %>
```

If you don't want the "second round trip" of a redirect you can substitute Response.Redirect with Server.Transfer. In that case the URL will not change in the user's browser.

Or, if you want you really want the redirect in IIS. Open IIS Manager, click your web site's node in the left pane, find "Http Redirect" in the main Features View pane and double-click.  Check the box for "Redirect Requests" then also check the box for "Only redirect requests to content in this directory (not subdirectories)". Note: the Server.Transfer option is not doable from IIS Manager.